# Removing keys from object via regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have this following object:

```
  {
      id: 'txn_000000000'
      customer: 'cus_00000000000000',
      customer_address: null,
      customer_email: 'foo@bar.com',
      customer_name: 'Foo Bar',
      customer_phone: null,
      customer_shipping: null,
      customer_tax_exempt: 'none',
      customer_tax_ids: [],
  }
```

I want to remove all keys from the object which start with `customer_` for GDPR reasons, do you know if this is possible in JS? (Specifically NodeJS)

Comment: Whats object key names go to to do with GDPR?

Comment: I want to remove keys which store things like the customer email and any other PII. @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is independant of NodeJs

Given your object `o`,
you can just filter the keys and reconstitute your object:

```js
const o = {
    id: 'txn_000000000',
    customer: 'cus_00000000000000',
    customer_address: null,
    customer_email: 'foo@bar.com',
    customer_name: 'Foo Bar',
    customer_phone: null,
    customer_shipping: null,
    customer_tax_exempt: 'none',
    customer_tax_ids: [],
}
let grpdCompliant = Object.keys(o).filter(k => {
  return !k.startsWith('customer_')
}).reduce((acc, k)=>{
  acc[k] = o[k]
  return acc
},{})
console.log(grpdCompliant)
```

---

edit: even better proposed by Andreas:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(e => !e[0].startsWith("customer_")))
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(e => !e[0].startsWith("customer_")));`

Comment: edited post accordingly @Andreas. Also thx for notifying me of this alternative, never really knew when I could make use of  ```fromEntries ``` and  ```entries ```

Comment: _"even better"_ - Not really better, just shorter^^

Answer (score 1):

if you fancy using lodash, you could do it in one line

```
  const _ = require("lodash");
_.pick(input, _.keys(input).filter(i => !i.startsWith("customer")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (/^customer_/.test(key)) {
    delete obj[key]
  }
}
```

where `obj` is your object.

*Note: using that technique your object will be mutated.*